# Show that $V = \{(x_1, x_1, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Show that
$V = \{(x_1, x_1, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3
: x_1, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace.

Can someone help with this question? I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: What is the definition of subspace?

Comment: That the subset is closed under vector addition, scalar multiplication and passes through the 0 vector. I'm just not sure how to start it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the zerovector $(0,0,0)$ is in $V$.

Suppose $(x_1,x_1,x_3), (y_1,y_1,y_3) \in V$. Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we have the following equalitie:
$$\lambda_1(x_1,x_1,x_3) + \lambda_2(y_1,y_1,y_3) = (\lambda_1x_1 + \lambda_2y_1, \lambda_1x_1 + \lambda_2y_1, \lambda_1x_3 + \lambda_2y_3)$$
and this is clearly an element of $V$. Therefore $V$ is a subspace of the vectorspace $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^3, +$.

As a general answer: whenever you have to check if some set is a subspace, check if the zero element is in the subspace and then take two arbitrary elements and two arbitrary scalars and show that the linear combination is in the given set.

Comment: "Then we have the following **inequalities**" inequalities? Do you perhaps mean *equality* or *equation* instead?

Comment: Yes yes of course! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the set of solutions of a system of linear homogeneous equations is a subspace (and viceversa), then note that
$$
V = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_{1} - x_{2} = 0 \},
$$
that is, $V$ is the space of solutions of the one-equation system
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{1} - x_{2} = 0.\\
\end{cases}
$$